# Launching chrome custom tabs killing closes in background

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-support-library, chrome-custom-tabs

Following is my code to launch chrome custom tab from android.

```
try {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.appthemecolor));
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebviewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.EXTRA_URL, url);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

If I launch chrome custom tabs 3 to 4 times it kills my application and launches new tab

This issue is occurring on **Jelly Bean** devices only

I am using following support library version

```
 compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try closing each tab down one-by-one before running application to see which tabs cause application to fail.